# Source code for the tray on top right corner. Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, system-tray

I am looking for source code for the top right corner tray icons. I want to know how they are being executed and wanted to make few modifications of my own if i can. I am on Ubuntu 12.04

[image]

The image on the top is the one I want to know about. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component which you are looking for, is called, Indicator Applet.

Here is the details about source code

https://code.launchpad.net/indicator-applet